# How would I save and load a datagridview c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, office-interop

I have a datagridview and already have a export function using Microsoft interop however i am struggling to find a solution to the loading the data.

My code to export to Excel:

```
       private void iSave()
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;

        app.Visible = true;
        worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Journal"];
        worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
        worksheet.Name = "Exported from Journal Pro";

        for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
        {
            worksheet.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

I also want it to add data from the second row as the first row is the title of the columns.
If theres a solution to use excel to load data in using the same format which is exported in i would be grateful :)

I am also open to other methods of saving, it doesn't have to be to an excel file.

I have used some other codes found online such as

`

```
using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    ofd.Filter = "Excel Files Only | *.xlsx; *.xls";
    ofd.Title = "Choose the File";
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        FileName_LBL.Text = ofd.FileName;
}





Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application xlapp;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook xlworkbook;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet xlworksheet;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet xlrange;
try
{
    xlapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    xlworkbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(FileName_LBL.Text);
    xlworksheet = xlworkbook.Worksheets["Exported from Journal Pro"];
    xlrange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)xlworksheet.UsedRange;

    dataGridView1.ColumnCount = xlrange.Columns.Count;

    for (int xlrow = 2; xlrow <= xlrange.Rows.Count; xlrow++)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(xlrange.Cells[xlrow, 2].Text, xlrange.Cells[xlrow, 3].Text, xlrange.Cells[xlrow, 4].Text, xlrange.Cells[xlrow, 5].Text, xlrange.Cells[xlrow, 6].Text, xlrange.Cells[xlrow, 7].Text);
    }
    xlworkbook.Close();
    xlapp.Quit();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

`

but i get errors such as **DISP_E_BADINDEX** and **E_NOINTERFACE**

Comment: It would be better to put data into a DataTable than directly into a DGV.  You can make then use datagridview1.DataSource = dt.  Then you can use the DataTable SaveXml method to write to file and ReadXml to restore the data table from a file.

Comment: @jdweng Cheers for that, i'll start on changing it. Thanks again :)

Comment: Hi, have you got any updates?

Comment: I had 2 datatables which I then combined into one and then used the SaveXML and LoadXML function, it works great with those. I left the export to excel code which somehow worked randomly.

Comment: Did my answer help you? I suggest that you rephrase your question so that you can be helped to solve it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this method to finish loading the data.

Step 1: Convert dataGridView to dataTable.

Step 2: Export dataTable to Excel .

Step 3: button calls the OutputExcel method.

Full Code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {             
        OutputExcel(dataGridView1);          
    }

public void OutputExcel(DataGridView dataGridView)
    {            
        string filePath = "";
        SaveFileDialog s = new SaveFileDialog();
        s.Title = "Excel";
        s.Filter = "Excel(*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
        s.FilterIndex = 1;
        if (s.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            filePath = s.FileName;
        else
            return;

        //Step 1: Convert dataGridView to dataTable

        DataTable tmpDataTable = new DataTable("tmpDataTable");
        DataTable modelTable = new DataTable("ModelTable");
        for (int column = 0; column < dataGridView.Columns.Count; column++)
        {
            if (dataGridView.Columns[column].Visible == true)
            {
                DataColumn tempColumn = new DataColumn(dataGridView.Columns[column].HeaderText, typeof(string));
                tmpDataTable.Columns.Add(tempColumn);
                DataColumn modelColumn = new DataColumn(dataGridView.Columns[column].Name, typeof(string));
                modelTable.Columns.Add(modelColumn);
            }
        }
        for (int row = 0; row < dataGridView.Rows.Count; row++)
        {
            if (dataGridView.Rows[row].Visible == false)
                continue;
            DataRow tempRow = tmpDataTable.NewRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < tmpDataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
                tempRow[i] = dataGridView.Rows[row].Cells[modelTable.Columns[i].ColumnName].Value;
            tmpDataTable.Rows.Add(tempRow);
        }
        if (tmpDataTable == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        //Step 2: Export dataTable to Excel
        long rowNum = tmpDataTable.Rows.Count;//line  
        int columnNum = tmpDataTable.Columns.Count;//column
        Excel.Application m_xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        m_xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
        m_xlApp.Visible = false;
        Excel.Workbooks workbooks = m_xlApp.Workbooks;
        Excel.Workbook workbook = workbooks.Add(Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
        Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[1];//Get sheet1
        try
        {
            string[,] datas = new string[rowNum + 1, columnNum];
            for (int i = 0; i < columnNum; i++) //Write field
                datas[0, i] = tmpDataTable.Columns[i].Caption;
            Excel.Range range = m_xlApp.Range[worksheet.Cells[1, 1], worksheet.Cells[1, columnNum]];
            range.Interior.ColorIndex = 15;
            range.Font.Bold = true;
            range.Font.Size = 10;

            int r = 0;
            for (r = 0; r < rowNum; r++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < columnNum; i++)
                {
                    object obj = tmpDataTable.Rows[r][tmpDataTable.Columns[i].ToString()];
                    datas[r + 1, i] = obj == null ? "" : "'" + obj.ToString().Trim();
                }
                Application.DoEvents();                   
            }                
            Excel.Range fchR = m_xlApp.Range[worksheet.Cells[1, 1], worksheet.Cells[rowNum + 1, columnNum]];
            fchR.Value2 = datas;

            worksheet.Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit();   
            m_xlApp.Visible = false;
            range = m_xlApp.Range[worksheet.Cells[1, 1], worksheet.Cells[rowNum + 1, columnNum]];
            range.Font.Size = 9;
            range.RowHeight = 14.25;
            range.Borders.LineStyle = 1;
            range.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            workbook.Saved = true;
            workbook.SaveCopyAs(filePath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Export Exception：" + ex.Message, "Export Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        m_xlApp.Workbooks.Close();
        m_xlApp.Workbooks.Application.Quit();
        m_xlApp.Application.Quit();
        m_xlApp.Quit();
        MessageBox.Show("Export successful!", "Tips", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
```

Effect：
[image]

[image]

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks for that, I apprieciate the effort you put in to help! I will try this

Comment: @5hihan Does it solve your problem? If you find the solution, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)